# How do I correctly send an OData $filter request?

Tags: odata, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger-UI to `GET` a record from a table using `Id` and `Name`.

I'm receiving an error from the api service:

[image]

How can I correctly format an OData `$filter` request to successfully query this endpoint?

Comment: try `curl https://localhost.com:3000/users?%24filter=id%20%27eq%27%203922488c-18bc-45d8-baa2-bdb10cd90e37 -H 'accept: application/json'`

Comment: without the encoding, /users?$filter=id 'eq' <uuid>